# How do I write Akane in Japanese?

Tags: names, input-method

I want to write Inoue Akane. I can write Inoue (井上) but I can't write Akane.

How would you change アカネ／あかね to 茜? It doesn't show up on the kanji bar thing (when you write in hiragana and you have to change it to kanji) so am I writing Akane wrong?

Comment: Akame is kind of an unusual name at best. Are you sure it is not Akemi? In any case, you cannot know the kanji given only the kana or romaji. Though the most common forms might make for a good guess. Various name dictionaries can help, for example [Jim Breen's WWWJDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1C). After "Dictionary" select "Japanese Names".

Comment: im sorry i meant Akane

Comment: I think the most common kanji for the female name Akane is 茜. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8C%9C#Japanese / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akane

Comment: ik, i need to know the reading. Like how Inoue is writing with i no ue then changed to the kanji 井上

Comment: You'll have to forgive my ignorance--is Inoue Akane the name of someone in particular or do you just want the name? If it's someone's name, you should look up a page about them that lists their legal name. If you're picking the name yourself, you can actually use literally any kanji you want if you supply the reading, but there are "common" kanji for names, and it may look strange if you don't use them. As mentioned above, 茜 is the most common. Or, lastly, if you're asking how to get the character to appear on your IME, you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Kurausukun yes thats what i was asking. I need it because its my friends name. But I can't keep copying and pasting her first name Akame. I can only write her last name thats Inoue so I call her Inoue online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are focused on the language itself, not on computer software that is required to use the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are doing everything correctly by typing `akane` in hiragana mode, which should give you `あかね`, and trying to convert it to kanji.

[image: akane]

In the list of suggestions when trying to convert あかね, you *should* get 茜 as a suggestion (my IME has it). If this doesn't work for you, you should be able to get it by its other reading せん.

[image]

If neither あかね nor せん convert to 茜 in your IME, you should always be able to add it as an option (in the "custom dictionary") to your IME. (Doing this, however, becomes a tech support question, which is off-topic for this site. You should be able to find a tutorial online for your IME.)

Comment: yea whenever I type Akane it gives me アカネ for some reason. The reason why I asked this here is because I thought I was somehow writing it wrong